# How to use a login form with Jetty 9?

Tags: authentication, jetty

I've just added authentication to my embedded jetty web server. I'm using the JDBCLoginService and everything works fine.

I now want to add a login page. And it doesn't work anymore: when the FormAuthenticator.validate method is called, it's trying to get an HTTPsession and none is found.

I've been trying to create Sessions but I've been unable to find the correct API. Can someone give me an example?

This my code:

```
// the file server part
ResourceHandler resource_handler = new ResourceHandler();
resource_handler.setDirectoriesListed(false);
resource_handler.setResourceBase("www");
resource_handler.setDirectoriesListed(false);
resource_handler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]{ "html/dashboard.html" });
// the JSP part
WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext();
webAppContext.setResourceBase("www");
webAppContext.setInitParameter("dirAllowed", "false");
webAppContext.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new QueryGlobals()), "/queries/globals");
webAppContext.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new QueryAllVenues()), "/queries/all_venues");
HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] {
        // static files
        resource_handler,
        // servlets
        webAppContext,
        // 404
        new DefaultHandler()
    });
// get the path for the authentication settings
// it should be in the same folder than the platform location
File configFile = new File(System.getProperty("com.bnpp.firefly.configfile"));
File authConfigFile = new File(configFile.getParent(), "auth.properties");
LoginService loginService = new org.eclipse.jetty.security.JDBCLoginService("MyRealm", authConfigFile.getPath());
m_server.addBean(loginService);

ConstraintSecurityHandler security = new ConstraintSecurityHandler();
Constraint constraint = new Constraint();
constraint.setName(Constraint.__FORM_AUTH);
constraint.setAuthenticate(true);
constraint.setRoles(new String[] { "user", "admin" });

ConstraintMapping mapping = new ConstraintMapping();
mapping.setPathSpec("/*");
mapping.setConstraint(constraint);

security.addConstraintMapping(mapping);
FormAuthenticator authenticator = new FormAuthenticator("/html/login.html", "/html/login.html", false);
security.setAuthenticator(authenticator);
security.setLoginService(loginService);


security.setHandler(handlers);
m_server.setHandler(security);


m_server.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. The trick is use only the WebAppContext. It provides:
* a SessionHandler
* a ResouceHandler
* and allow to setup a SecurityHandler

My code is now:

```
// Creating the server on port webPort
m_server = new Server(webPort);

// get the path for the authentication settings
// it should be in the same folder than the platform location
File configFile = new File(System.getProperty("com.bnpp.firefly.configfile"));
File authConfigFile = new File(configFile.getParent(), "auth.properties");
// set the login service
LoginService loginService = new org.eclipse.jetty.security.JDBCLoginService("MyRealm", authConfigFile.getPath());
ConstraintSecurityHandler security = new ConstraintSecurityHandler();

// no authentication for these items
{
    Constraint constraint = new Constraint();
    constraint.setAuthenticate(false);

    for (String pathSpec: new String[] {
            "/images/*",
            "/css/*",
            "/lib/*",
        })
    {
        ConstraintMapping mapping = new ConstraintMapping();
        mapping.setPathSpec(pathSpec);
        mapping.setConstraint(constraint);
        security.addConstraintMapping(mapping);
    }
}

// must have authentication for the rest
{
    Constraint constraint = new Constraint();
    constraint.setName(Constraint.__FORM_AUTH);
    constraint.setAuthenticate(true);
    constraint.setRoles(new String[] { "user", "admin" });

    ConstraintMapping mapping = new ConstraintMapping();
    mapping.setPathSpec("/*");
    mapping.setConstraint(constraint);
    security.addConstraintMapping(mapping);
}

security.setLoginService(loginService);

FormAuthenticator authenticator = new FormAuthenticator("/html/login.html", "/html/login.html?error=true", false);
security.setAuthenticator(authenticator);

// the JSP part
WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext();
//webAppContext.setContextPath("/");
webAppContext.setResourceBase("www");
webAppContext.setInitParameter("dirAllowed", "false");

//Including the JSTL jars for the webapp.
webAppContext.setAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern",".*/[^/]*jstl.*\\.jar$");

//Enabling the Annotation based configuration
org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration.ClassList classlist = org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration.ClassList.setServerDefault(m_server);
classlist.addAfter("org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration", "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration", "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration");
classlist.addBefore("org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration", "org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration");

webAppContext.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new QueryGlobals()), "/queries/globals");
webAppContext.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new QueryAllVenues()), "/queries/all_venues");
webAppContext.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new QuerySearchCSV()), "/queries/searchCSV");
webAppContext.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new QuerySearchWithPaging()), "/queries/searchWithPaging");
webAppContext.setWelcomeFiles(new String [] {"html/dashboard.html"});

// this will set authentication
webAppContext.setSecurityHandler(security);
webAppContext.getSessionHandler().setMaxInactiveInterval(24 * 60 * 60);

// what the server serves
m_server.setHandler(webAppContext);

m_server.start();
```